# While checking man file in youtube-dl

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, youtube, manpage, youtube-dl

Commend: `man youtube-dl`

Output :

```
No manual entry for youtube-dl
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

how to resolve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Please add more info

Comment: `man youtube-dl` , online example  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/youtube-dl.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt install youtube-dl` provides `/usr/share/man/man1/youtube-dl.1.gz`